# Suppress warnings in testthat functions introduces error

Tags: r, testthat

I have a function in my package that uses tryCatch for condition handling.

```
f <- function(){
  tryCatch(expr =  warning("?!"), error = function(c) {message(c); 3},
           warning = function(c) {message(c); 4})
}
```

When I try to write a unit test for this with testthat, I always get an error related to restart or muffleWarning. Any idea how to solve this? I want to match output to 4 during warning, in this case.

```
test_that("test_f", {
  suppressWarnings(output <- f())
  expect_equal(output, 4)
})

> devtools::test()
 error: test_f
no 'restart' 'muffleWarning' found
Backtrace:
  1. base::suppressWarnings(output <- f()) tests/testthat/test_file.R:27:2
 14. base::invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
```

version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
os       Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
system   x86_64, linux-gnu
testthat  * 2.3.2

Comment: When I run your code, I see the `?!` that the `message` puts out, and the test succeeds without the `no 'restart'` problem.

Comment: This is strange. Could you specify which r and testthat version you have used?

Comment: R-4.0.2, testthat-2.3.2, on win10

Comment: However ... I can reproduce your error in R-3.5.3 (testthat-2.3.1), so it's certainly an R-version thing.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/874, https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17598 (mirrored in https://github.com/MichaelChirico/r-bugs/issues/6772)

Comment: My guess (without much testing) is that your issue will be resolved if you update from R-3.6 to R-4.0. Is that feasible? Another option is to remove `suppressWarnings`, as without that call, it still succeeds in both R-4.0 and R-3.5.3.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans . It is possible, I should have done that before. Thanks for clarifying